# При локализации с помощью i18n vue js, в теге script происходит перевод только после перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, vue.js, i18n

При локализации с помощью i18n vue js, в теге script происходит перевод только после перезагрузки страницы. Код скрипта выглядит следующим образом:

```
data() {
    const titleName = this.$t('name')
    return {
      showTable: false,
      interships: [],

      heads: [
        { id: 'name', title: this.$t('name') },
        { id: 'type', title: this.$t('type') },
        { id: 'description', title: this.$t('description') },
        { id: 'beginDate', title: this.$t('beginData'), columnWidth: '75px', type: 'date' },
        { id: 'endDate', title: this.$t('endData'), columnWidth: '75px', type: 'date' }
      ]
    }
  },
```

В самом template эти данные используются в компоненте PTable:

```
<PTable
      v-show="showTable"
      :heads="heads"
      :params="dataTable"
      is-edit
      is-delete
      @edit-row="intershipModal"
      @delete-row="deleteIntership"
    />
```

Сам перевод работает корректно, однако при смене языка (например с ангийского на русский) локализация происходит только после перезагрузки страницы, как это можно исправить?
Сами файлы с переводами лежат в папке locale и там есть 2 файла en.json и ru.json

Comment: Сделайте строки с переводом вычисляемым свойством.